# What is the difference between a socialist, a democratic socialist and a social democrat?

Tags: government, ideology, socialism, democratic-socialism

What are the primary differences between socialism, democratic socialism and social democracy? Are they simply three branches of a the same ideology?

Primarily in theory, but if you can give any examples of how they have been implemented in practice that would be helpful

Comment: The problem with these terms is that they have vastly different meanings to different people, depending on location and political orientation.

Comment: To overcome the subjectivity problem, you may want to edit it this question to be what would a conservative and a progressive say the differences are between these groups of thought.

Comment: Have you rfeviewed the relevant definitions (at least, Wikipedia) and if so, what details are you missing?

Comment: Unless this question is reframed to state a given contemporary critic --or critics if you want to break it down into more questions--like how would a Beard on the left or a Jaffa or Strauss on the right view these terms-- I don't know how you handle this question. Even then it would be exceeding difficult.  Voting to close

Comment: @KDog we're not here to critique every political concept from multiple partisan standpoints, as that wouldn't be a Q/A site. That'd be a political debate site.

Comment: @blip and yet, sometimes objective truth can only be found in adversarial argument and debate.  The up and down voting tacitly recognizes that.

Comment: @KDog I won't disagree with you on that point. I'm just saying it doesn't work well on the SE format.

Answer (score -3):

Socialist - Abolishment of private property, all property belongs to the state except personal property, this may vary in some socialist nations such as Britain but general principle. Government is a primary competitor and provides all welfare and essential services, though depending on the country may also allow private competitors in these areas.

Democratic Socialist - Private Property stays private. Welfare programs are entirely managed by the government along with CRITICAL services, commonly seen as healthcare, retirement programs, etc.

Social Democrat - Government is a competitor not sole provider for Critical services and should offer them. Welfare is given by the government though private businesses may provide the service, but the service will be offered, i.e. Government pays PECO to give you electricity.

Along with the strictness of the system comes higher taxation and necessity for income redistribution and additional government oversight.

As far as ideology goes they are on the same track, they just break down more and more into the role of the government in the lives of its people and the extent that the means of production must be seized.

In general there are many types of Socialism as an ideological concept
http://www.philosophybasics.com/branch_socialism.html - includes the history of socialism with descriptions of each of the systems and conflicting views

What I describe as a Socialist is adherent to Libertarian Socialism

As for Social Democrat describes as the gradual transition from Socialism to Capitalism
https://www.britannica.com/topic/social-democracy

Comment: Out of curiosity why the downvote?

Comment: I would assume you got downvoted because this answer reads like your personal opinion. To back it up, you might want to reference it with some proper citations from the political theorists who coined these terms.

Comment: @Philipp  And noted critical analysts.  Objectivity is rather key here.

Comment: @KDog I don't know where I have injected any opinion into the matter. If I've used any negative language just let me know so I might remove it but I have no objection to anything I have written as the necessity varies between areas

Comment: I didn't down vote or suggest that you weren't objective to the extent that anyone can be.  I just wouldn't want to get a definition of Socialism from Marx, Chavez or the NYTs for that matter.  It would much rather it come from say Buckley or Jaffa. Or at least an acknowledgement of the contrast between these two groups of thought.

Comment: @KDog I see updated with the links I've used and description

Comment: Sources added that provide critical analysis of each aspect from all points of views and more down votes. I feel like my girlfriends giving me the cold shoulder but won't explain

Comment: I think you are trying to describe a label with a concept that theoretically should come from the philosophy.  But the labels do not really follow the philosophy they are derived from.

Your answer would be fine for what is Socialism, democratic socialism, and Social Democracy... but not necessarily the labels that candidates take on

Comment: "socialist States such as Britain": what?!

Comment: @SoylentGray not to belabor this, but the question title is answered and no percise implementation of either is given and wiggle room is shown displaying the primary difference of each as transcribed by their base theory.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I tend to like the word State, which may at times be incorrect, to refer to sovereign bodies but it is a nation so fixed.

Comment: @SCFi: my query isn't about "state", which is certainly suitable here; it's about labelling the UK as "socialist" - especially since it's had a centre-right or right-wing government for the last 7 years (and possibly the next 5).

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Please read my first source.  Personally I refer to Britain as socialist because it acts as a primary competitor in the private market and has a monopoly on some areas of industry and provides all welfare services its self. Just because policies change does not mean that government responsibility or for lack of a better term "Mission Statement" has not changed.

Comment: This is a fine answer, but so are the comments, which I think only shows that these terms mean different things in different context and aren't easily definable generically.

Comment: @SCFi - Actually its not the question title is socialist... you answered what socialism is... there is a huge difference.  The question itself asked socialism but you used socialist in your answer... to me that makes your answer wrong.  I am not trying to argue with you just explain my perception and downvote

Comment: @SoylentGray I understand and enjoy the discussion to come to a conclusion. From my stand point a practitioner of the ideology is a believer in the core values, perhaps that assumption maybe incorrect as people can identify however they feel but in that case it would be impossible to answer. As such we take the common themes throughout the theories and apply that to a generalized belief set. Answering the difference between the Ideologies is to answer the most common difference between the individual, If the questioner wanted racial, gender, or any other traits, well don't have those

Comment: And I disagree with that premise.

Comment: What you call a social democrat is actually a social-liberal (socialist and in favor of economic liberalism, hence the competition between the state and private sector). Granted, most european social democrat parties have become social liberals, but it was not always the case, some used to be in favor of state owned monopoles for healthcare, schooling, telecommunications, ...